# Calling RequestMapping "twice"

Tags: java, spring, maven, thymeleaf

I couldn't figure out what to put to the title, but I have the following code:

```
@Controller
public class WorkdayAddController {
@Autowired
private WorkdayRepository workdayRepository; 

@Autowired
private VehicleRepository vehicleRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "addworkday")
public String addWorkday(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("workdayaddform", new WorkdayAddForm());
    model.addAttribute("vehicles", vehicleRepository.findAll());
    return "addworkday";
}   

@RequestMapping(value = "saveworkday", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("workdayaddform") WorkdayAddForm workdayaddform, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) { // validation errors
        Date workdayBegin = workdayaddform.getBeginDate();
        Date workdayEnd = workdayaddform.getEndDate();
        if (!UtilityClass.dateIsAfterDate(workdayBegin, workdayEnd)) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("beginDate", "err.beginDate", "Aloitusaika ei voi olla lopetusajan jälkeen.");
            return "addworkday";    
        }
        Workday workday = new Workday();
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        workdayRepository.save(workday);
    }
    else {
        return "addworkday";
    }
    return "redirect:/workdaylist";     
}    

}
```

After the 'dateIsAfterDate' check, it should direct one to 'addworkday' again, which it does, but it doesn't add the 'vehicles' model. Is there a way around this? I thought it would somehow just direct it to the above @RequestMapping(value= "addworkday") but this seems to not be the case.

**Update:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addworkday")
public String addWorkday(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    System.out.println(redirectAttributes); // {}
    System.out.println(model);  // output in comment
    model.addAttribute("workdayaddform", new WorkdayAddForm()); //I guess I need to add the old workdayform here?
    model.addAttribute("vehicles", vehicleRepository.findAll());
    return "addworkday";
} 

 @RequestMapping(value = "saveworkday", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("workdayaddform") WorkdayAddForm workdayaddform, 
                       BindingResult bindingResult,
                       final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) { // validation errors
            Date workdayBegin = workdayaddform.getBeginDate();
            Date workdayEnd = workdayaddform.getEndDate();

            if (!UtilityClass.dateIsAfterDate(workdayBegin, workdayEnd)) {
                // Add the vehicle you want to send to the other method.
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("workdayaddform", workdayaddform);
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("vehicle", vehicleRepository.findAll());
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("binding", bindingResult);
                return "redirect:/addworkday";    
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `@RedirectedAttributes` annotation in order to send attributes to another method in a controller. Also, you will need to add "redirect:/" to your returned url.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "saveworkday", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("workdayaddform") WorkdayAddForm workdayaddform, 
                       BindingResult bindingResult,
                       final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) { // validation errors
            Date workdayBegin = workdayaddform.getBeginDate();
            Date workdayEnd = workdayaddform.getEndDate();

            if (!UtilityClass.dateIsAfterDate(workdayBegin, workdayEnd)) {
                // Add the vehicle you want to send to the other method.
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("vehicle", vehicle);
           redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("binding", bindingResult);
                return "redirect:/addworkday";    
            }
        // More code.
        else {
           redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("vehicle", new Vehicle());
           return "redirect:/addworkday"; 
        }
    }
```

I wasn't sure if you meant, after the in the `else` or inside the `if`, so I add them in both places, just to make sure.

Comment: Thanks, this works but errors are not displayed. So I guess I need to find a way to also send the binding to the method.

Comment: That is just another attribute you need to add. I just edited my answer. Hope it works.

Comment: Hmm. I can access the binding result from model, but redirectAttributes show as an empty dict {}. Adding just BindingResult as an argument wasn't as simple as I thought, so I had to scrap that.
I updated my current progress in the first post.

Comment: So did you managed to solve it? You can always dismantle your binding result in smaller parts, like the error messages and send them like Strings. You will have more attributes, but it will work for sure.

Comment: I guess I'll get it fixed eventually, your answer answered my original question anyway so I'm accepting it.